# JProfiler Heap Walker - select objects that are held by GC Root located in specific Java packages

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jprofiler, gc-roots

I have JavaFX application and I have made Heap Snaphot using JProfiler 10.1.5. My current object set (filtered using "use new" selection step) has 46064 objects in 672 classes. 
I would like to narrow the search range for memory leaks, and filter my current object set to have only objects that are held by GC Roots located in specific java packages. Is it possible? Are there any other tools which can do such a search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get to that is to go to the "References" view of the heap walker, select the "Merged dominating references" mode and then "GC roots to objects" in the drop-down next to the view mode selector.